# Dependency jar for intercepting and writing rabbitmq messages to DB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-aop

Is it possible to:

1. Create a jar which has AOP annotation(custom) for intercepting rabbitmq listener to write the message to DB.
2. Pass this jar around as dependency to other spring based applications to get their messages in the DB.

Need clarifications:
1. How do we read the method argument, message here?
2. Can pointcut be read from properties so that any application using it provides its own pointcut by adding a property in like application.properties
3. Is there any special consideration about when the jar will be loaded so that the functionality is available as soon as the application starts?